# How to setup in xkb caps lock to vim keys and to regular Caps at the same time?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm currently using the Caps key as `ISO_Level3_shift` and I'm mapping the h,j,k,l,$ and 0 to vim keys. It works and everything is fine. However, I use SQL and I want to write all the code for SQL in capital letters so it would be hard to press the shift key while typing every letter. So, what I want is someway of using this vim keys as is, but also having the ability to toggle Caps lock when doing some SQL programming. maybe something like holding it for a while or pressing shift+caps to toggle it back.

I'm using XKB to achieve what I'm doing as xmodmap doesn't work for me as I use a second layout which will not work correctly if I use xmodmap.

Here is my `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file - or at least part of it where I set my current setup:

```
    key <AC06> {    [     h,    H,  Left        ]   };
    key <AC07> {    [     j,    J,  Down        ]   };
    key <AC08> {    [     k,    K,  Up      ]   };
    key <AC09> {    [     l,    L,  Right       ]   };
    key <AE10> {    [     0,    parenright, Home    ]   };
    key <AE04> {    [     4,    dollar, End     ]   };
    key <CAPS> {    [  ISO_Level3_Shift             ]       };
```

this portion is inside the

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {}
```

block

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with one of these commands:

Swap esc with caps: `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape`

Shift + caps turn on capslock: `setxkbmap -option caps:escape_shifted_capslock`

Just run one of them at startup, you can add it to your `~/.xprofile`

source: `man xkeyboard-config` & `man setxkbmap`